# Loading Bundles to/from files on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm moving over to doing some Android coding, and something that I do frequently is create plists which contain my static list items.  This aids greatly when I have to do multi-tiered list views where users drill down to find information.  (e.g. Continent --> Country --> City )  What I do then, is code one list view that pushes copies of itself drilling deeper into the data tree.

However, on Android, I can't seem to find any kind of equivalent to a plist that will let me do the above (without creating an SQL database).

So what I've ended up doing is hard-coding everything... which is not what I want to be doing.  There are a ton of xml resources available to Android and that's the pattern I feel like I should be following.

```
ArrayList<Bundle> data = new ArrayList<Bundle>();

Bundle infoHeader = new Bundle();
infoHeader.putInt(keyText,R.string.stay_informed);
infoHeader.putInt(keyLayout,R.layout.main_header);
data.add(infoHeader);

Bundle readAction = new Bundle();
readAction.putInt(keyText,R.string.read);
readAction.putInt(keySubtext, R.string.read_substr);
readAction.putInt(keyLayout, R.layout.main_row_blue);
// link to new ArrayList of items for the next level down
data.add(readAction);
```

What I want to do is the following (or something very similar to it):

```
<resources>
<array name="main_list">
    <extra>
        <string name="keyText" value="@string/stay_informed" />
        <layout name="keyLayout" value="@layout/main_header" />
    </extra>
    <extra>
        <string name="keyText" value="@string/read" />
        <string name="keySubtext" value="@string/read_substr" />
        <layout name="keyLayout" value="@layout/main_row_blue" />
        <!-- <string name="keyLink" value="@array/detail_list" /> Where detail_list has more Bundles -->
    </extra>
</array>
</resource>
```

And just load that Array of Bundles at run-time instead of having it hard-coded into the app.

So. How can I efficiently store/retrieve the equivalent of a `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` on Android?

(I've discovered the [android plist parser](https://github.com/tenaciousRas/android-plist-parser/wiki/Android-PList-Parser), but I want to know how it can be done on Android)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll give this a shot.  I'm currently working from Android to iOS (the exact opposite of yourself) so I understand what you are trying do (I think).  Java doesn't have "Dictionaries" but it does have HashMaps (key / value pairing - same thing).  If you really want to, you can persist your objects using serialization to a file that you can package up in your assets folder in Android.  You can then read (but not write) this info whenever you like.

Here is a link to help you with serializing Java objects.  Do a search for HashMaps in Java and you will see a ton of stuff.  If you are going to put many different types of objects in this HashMap, don't use generics.  (They look like this `<String, String>` ).  Leave those out to make a raw HashMap.

To serialize: (when you persist it)
http://www.javadb.com/writing-objects-to-file-with-objectoutputstream

To deserialize: (when you read it back in)
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/DeserializeObj.html

Another way which is perhaps simpler, is to just create an XML file, (like what you have done above) and store it in assets.  You can then parse it with XMLPullParser when the app starts and store it in memory for the duration of the app, though you will not be able to use "@layout, @string", etc.

Comment: Not being able to use @string sortof defeats the purpose when working with a localizable model.

Comment: Also, XMLPullParser seems a bit overkill... I just need key/value pairing.